# MySQL query to select a record from each group that meets a user-defined criterion

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am looking for a query that selects a record from each group that meets a user-defined criterion.  I can explain with the following illustrative table:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table
(
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  categoryID INT,
  weight INT,

  PRIMARY KEY(id)  
);
```

The table is populated as follows:

```
INSERT INTO sample_table(categoryID, weight) VALUES(1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 2), (2, 5), (2, 3), (2, 9), (3, 5), (3, 3), (3, 3);
```

A simple `GROUP BY categoryID` query returns the first record in each group, as shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table GROUP BY categoryID;
+----+------------+--------+
| id | categoryID | weight |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 |          1 |      3 |
|  4 |          2 |      5 |
|  7 |          3 |      5 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

To return the last record in each group we can use the approach [suggested here](https://paulund.co.uk/get-last-record-in-each-mysql-group):

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM sample_table GROUP BY categoryID);
+----+------------+--------+
| id | categoryID | weight |
+----+------------+--------+
|  3 |          1 |      2 |
|  6 |          2 |      9 |
|  9 |          3 |      3 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

**However**, what I want to do is to select the record which the highest value for the `weight` field in each group.  My output, therefore, should be:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id | categoryID | weight |
+----+------------+--------+
|  2 |          1 |      5 |
|  6 |          2 |      9 |
|  7 |          3 |      3 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

---

Kindly suggest the `GROUP BY categoryID` query which will yield the above output.

Comment: *A simple GROUP BY categoryID query returns the first record in each group* No. It returns some record. Today this some occures to be "first".

Answer (score 0):

> select the record which the highest value for the weight field in each group.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT id, categoryID, weight,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY categoryID ORDER BY weight DESC, id) rn
             FROM sample_table)
SELECT id, categoryID, weight
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=279383eb2f1ec1b230011f515d047c61)

I.e. we enumerate rows in a group by `categoryID` ordering them by `weight` decrease, then get 1st row in each group.